# How to use runAlways SQL changeSet

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I'm testing LiquiBase, so I created first changelog to test installation and setup and it worked

```sql
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset bob:1
create table test1 (
    id int primary key,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

what I want to test is runAlways, so I created new changeset:

```
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset betlista:4
-- runAlways: true
insert into test1(id, name) values( 
      (select nvl(max(id) + 1, 1) from test1)
    , 'test ' || sysdate
);
```

and my expectation is, when I'll run it (without version increase) it will insert the new record into table, but it is not. It is inserting only when I increased version.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found a problems

- there cannot be space after `runAlways:`
- it has to be on one line with changeset

This worked fine for me

```sql
-- liquibase formatted sql

-- changeset betlista:8 runAlways:true
insert into test1(id, name) values( 
      (select nvl(max(id) + 1, 1) from test1)
    , 'test 8 ' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
);
```

**Alternative**

In the previous example, the changelog was SQL based and of course, this is not the only option.

I prefer changelog as XML (as I can have code completion in my IDE) and to have the scripts as SQL (as most people are familiar with it).

So the solution is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-3.8.xsd ">

    <changeSet id="10" author="betlista" runAlways="true">
        <sqlFile path="insert_test1.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

```sql
insert into test1(id, name) values( 
      (select nvl(max(id) + 1, 1) from test1)
    , 'test 10 ' || to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
);
```